# 2 conditional if statement with string equal null

Tags: java, null, conditional-statements

I am striking out with a 2 conditional if statement

I am wanting if( an integer == 0 && a string != null)

Here is the code:

```
int Coefficient = 0;
String Selection = null;

 if(Coefficient == 0 && Selection != null ){
```

elsewhere in my code this condition does work:

```
if(Selection == null){
            System.out.println("No Data");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Data Selected");
```

also the Selection string comes from a "JComboBox"
    Selection = (String)SelectionComboBox.getSelectedItem();

with the if(Coefficient == 0 && Selection != null ){

I am getting a .NullPointerException

I know that 
    if(Coefficient == 0)

by itself drops me in correctly

I have tried

```
if(Coefficient == 0 && !Selection.equals(null) ){
if(Coefficient == 0 & Selection.equals(null) ){
if(Coefficient == 0 && Selection != null ){
if(Coefficient == 0 && !Selection.isEmpty()){
```

all give the same error

Here is the code in I hope a complete enough to "compile" and demonstrate:

```
int Coefficient = 0;
String Selection = null;

System.out.printf("Source = %s\n",Selection);
        if(Coefficient == 0 && Selection != null ){ 
            System.out.printf(" HERE Selection = %s\n",Selection);

        }

private void SelectionComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    Selection = (String)SelectionComboBox.getSelectedItem();

}
```

The printf outside the if gives "Selection = null"
This gives Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

I am using NetBeans and I noticed a "hint" or some such that read Invert If - does this help?

Help?

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason that this check throws NPE:  if(Coefficient == 0 && Selection == null )

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `Selection == null` to check if `Selection` is `null` (unless you want to check that it's not null). Please provide us with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing your problem. Also, empty and null are two completely different things.

Comment: Provide exception and matching line number. Your if check is just fine.

Comment: sorry - I meant != null is the case that is not working, I have changed my question accordingly

Comment: As an aside, your code will be easier to read if you start your variable names, such as Coefficient, in lower case.

Comment: a line number from the stack trace + matching line of code is all we need.

Comment: Your added code still doesn't help. There is no possible way the provided code can throw an NPE. Please provide a COMPLETE (but short) program reproducing your problem.

Comment: If it's easier for you, I guess a good screenshot of the code along with the stack trace will be also helpful...

Comment: I have a "working" solution but does not satisfies my curiosity - if I do this in two conditional statements it works: if( Selection != null) { if Coefficient == 0){

Comment: WHy won't you take the help people offer you and provide a stacktrace + matching line number? The problem is simply that noone believes you when you say that that particular line is the root cause of the NPE, because it isn't possible. Until you show it is possible, noone will believe you. Or if the root cause is somewhere else then we can progress.

Comment: ok - since the verdict is my code cannot throw the error - I generated a sample program doing just this function and as you know - it worked with no error. I have gone back and retyped the conditional statement if (coefficient == 0 && selection != null) and now it works fine. My apologies I had commented out the original statement and the old and new are identical. I don't know?   @Aaron - my code is 1000+ lines of code and the variable names are long and messy and I was trying to keep it simple. I generated the simple code to do just that provide the full stacktrace and so forth

Comment: Since the sample code worked that sent me back to my original - thanks for the help and I am sorry for what appears to be wasted time Obvious (duh) it's not the retyping - it is something I had wrong.

Comment: @user2137258 If there's a next time, you could just take the line from the stacktrace which shows which line number the NPE happens in, and then also provide just the matching line number of code, and perhaps any surrounding code if it initialised variables, etc.  No need for all 1000 lines - just enough to prove that we're either on a wild goose chase, or not : )

Comment: @Aaron Will do. - lesson learned

Comment: For future reference, you should provide us with a complete program reproducing the problem (one that we can just copy into a file, compile and run - it should work if we do this, it shouldn't complain about missing variables, it should be wrapped in a class, have a main method, and everything, and it should actually reproduce the problem). That's exactly what is written at [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), which is why I pointed you there in my first comment. Since the question is unlikely to help future visitors, and doesn't have an upvoted answer, you should delete it.